# Spoof / Detect Browser Requests with NodeJS or other

Tags: node.js, http, security, browser, spoofing

- My website makes http post requests to a 3rd party public api. They work flawlessly.
- If I make the same requests via a NodeJS script locally I get either 403 or 500 errors depending on the headers I sent.

Questions:

- Can servers reliably detect if a request comes from a browser or not?
- How are servers detecting it?
- Is there a way to spoof a browser request with NodeJS or other?

```js
// This is what I tried.
// Headers are copied from my website's actual requests via Chrome Dev Tool's network tab.
const https = require('https')

const options = {
    host: 'api.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/form',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.7',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length': '127',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Host: 'api.com',
        Origin: 'https://www.mywebsite.com',
        Referer: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
    },
    form: {
        name: 'My Name'
    }
};

const req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
})

req.end();
```

Comment: Take a proxy (like Burp, ZAP, or on Windows, Fiddler, etc) and compare your requests. There will be a difference, because the server only has the request and nothing else, they cannot magically differentiate.

Comment: So you are saying servers can not differentiate between browser and server requests if the same headers are present and that it is possible to set all relevant headers server side? I will try your recommendation. Thank you!

Comment: You want me to use one of the mentioned services to proxy the request my website makes, because this would proof that it is possible, because these services are doing a server side request, correct? If this works, it would mean there is something wrong with the headers I put in my node script. Although I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Technically it is possible to manage access (ie. throw a 403 or not) based on things like source IP, the sequence of previous calls (say a token received earlier in a cookie) and so on, but it is not possible to authenticate (~differentiate) the client software. If your browser can make a valid request, so can your server-side client, for sure (but it is not true the other way round, a browser will not be able to make any request an arbitrary programmed client can, because some things like the origin are set by the browser itself, also a browser will only be able to make valid http requests).

Comment: Made it work. Thanks again! I intercepted my NodeJS request with HTTP Toolkit, because I could not make Fiddler work. There I noticed that the x-www-form-urlencoded form data was not sent along. In the form data the client id and secret are needed. This is why I was getting 403. Using Node's 'request' module instead of 'https' module I was able to sent the form data along and now I can make requests via Node.